# Calling Python from MATLAB with system(): issue importing non-standard Python libraries

Tags: python, matlab

test1.py contains:

```
import sys
print 'ok'
```

test2.py contains:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
print 'ok'
```

Both `python test1.py` and `python test2.py` work fine.

When I'm in MATLAB, `system('python test1.py')` works while `system('python test2.py')`  doesn't work and throw the following error message:

```
>> system('python test2.py')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 137, in <module>
    import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 9, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from polynomial import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py", line 17, in <module>
    from numpy.linalg import eigvals, lstsq
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from linalg import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 23, in <module>
    from numpy.linalg import lapack_lite
ImportError: /afs/csail.mit.edu/system/common/matlab/2012a/sys/os/glnxa64/libgfortran.so.3: version `GFORTRAN_1.4' not found (required by /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3gf)
```

Full stack:

[image]

I use Matlab 2012a x64 on Ubuntu 12.04 with Python 2.7. Any idea why Python called from MATLAB fails to import non-standard Python libraries (here Numpy, but I had the same issue with Scipy)? Note that everything works fine on my Windows computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same problem is on Ubuntu 14.04 x64 with Matlab R2013a.

The problem is that matlab comes with some of its own libraries, in this case `libgfortran.so.3` instead of using the system ones. From what I googled they are usually outdated, and numpy requires newer versions. Thus there is a problem.

In Ubuntu, it was enough to change the libraries. Don't know how to do it on windows ( I guess it would be somehow similar), but in Ubuntu it is as follows:

**First**: go to:

```
 `cd /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/sys/os/glnxa64`
```

**Second**: make backup of matlab's `libgfortran.so.3`:

```
 `sudo mv libgfortran.so.3 libgfortran.so.3.bck`
```

**Third**: sym link system library:

```
 `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3`
```

Comment: Thanks, this is bad news for me as in my case MATLAB is on some shared network volume so I cannot touch its libraries... isn't there any way to force MATLAB to call Python and give it the same environment as if Python  was called from shell? I don't understand why MATLAB forces Python to use its (outdated) libraries.

Comment: I pinged the MATLAB newsgroup to see whether there is any way to force MATLAB not to screw the Python's environment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/336157

Comment: Problem solved, see my answer. Thanks Marcin for pointing me to the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't have permission to edit your MATLAB directory such as in my case where MATLAB is located on a shared drive, or you  just want to temporarily change which libraries MATLAB should call, you can use the [LD_PRELOAD trick](https://stackoverflow.com/q/426230/395857), which allows you to have a file (typically a library) loaded before any other library.

For this question, the issue was that as Marcin pointed out NumPy requires a newer version of `libgfortran.so.3` that the one provided by MATLAB, so we need to pre-load the system version of `libgfortran.so.3` (which should be up-to-date and subsequently working with Numpy) with the following command in the shell:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3 matlab
```

---

If you want to make sure that all the features of NumPy and SciPy are working with in MATLAB, you can create the file `good_luck.py` containing:

```
import numpy
numpy.test('full')

import scipy
scipy.test('full')
```

Then in MATLAB call it with system: `system('python good_luck.py')`.

If you need to preload more than one files, which is likely to happen, as usual use `:` to concatenate them, e.g.:

`LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16: matlab`

---

I would still prefer to have a solution that would force MATLAB to call Python and give it the same environment as if Python was called from shell. It's quite a pain to have to manually preload the libraries that the Python code needs, and I still don't understand why MATLAB by default forces Python to use its (outdated) libraries.