# scikit learn lib/libgfortran.so.3: version `GFORTRAN_1.4' not found

Tags: python, ubuntu, import, scikit-learn, libraries

I import a module called linear_model from sklearn:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
```

and here is what I get:

```
ImportError: /home/masha/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/..
/lib/libgfortran.so.3: version `GFORTRAN_1.4' not found (required 
by /usr/lib/libblas.so.3)
```

I was trying to find some information about this problem but all of the questions seem to occur with different libraries on different systems so the advices are really different and I don't know what to do. If it matters, I work on Ubuntu 14.04.
In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23946879/calling-python-from-matlab-with-system-issue-importing-non-standard-python-li) it says: "In Ubuntu, it was enough to change the libraries."
So... maybe I just have to change the libraries? How should I do it?

Comment: It looks like you didn't install all dependencies. Follow the steps in http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html and let me know if you still have this problem.

Comment: Actually, I think I solved it! I tried following the instructions for the question I linked above and I just included a path to Canopy instead of matlab and I think it worked! (still debugging but seeing different errors)

But thanks for the advise anyway!